# Excel If and or statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

```
=IF(AND(F5>=15,M5,IF(AND(F5="SM",M5="PRSU",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PRSU",M5))))
```

I need this formula to return a `1` if `F5` is `0>=15` OR if `F5=”SM”` and if it finds `"PRSU"` in `M5`

in this instance `M5` is `"Simplicity(PRSU, PR15)"` but it won't always contain `"PRSU"`

Comment: `AND(F5>=15, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PRSU",M5)))` is what you want to test

Comment: =IF(AND(F13>=15,COUNTIF(M13,"*PRSU*")),1,0) This is returning a 1 regradless of if F13 is >=15 or not?

Comment: is the `0>=15` a typo? (should it be `>=15`?). Also Excel doesn't like this formula if I try it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this Formula (If I've understood this correctly):

```
=IF(OR(IF(ISNUMBER(F5),IF(F5>=15,1)),IF(AND(F5="SM",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PRSU",M5))),1)),1)
```

My understanding (in a sort of pseudocode):

> IF [ (F5 is a number 15 or greater) OR ( F5 is SM and PRSU appears in M5) ] { output "1" }